# Как отслеживать кто нажал на реакцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
import asyncio
import sqlite3

from discord import channel
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import discord

conn = sqlite3.connect('aern.db')

TOKEN = 'token'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

client = commands.Bot


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def poll(ctx, *, text):
    message = await ctx.send(text)
    for emoji in ('', ''):
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)


async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
        channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id) #канал
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) #сообщение
        user = get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) #пользователь, который поставил реакцию
        emoji = str(payload.emoji)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

`on_raw_reaction_add(payload)` - никак не срабатывает, т.е бот не реагирует на события

Answer (score 1):

Хех, вы не указали `@bot.event`,  перед событием

Код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id) #канал
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) #сообщение
    user = get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) #пользователь, который поставил реакцию
    emoji = str(payload.emoji)
```

Да и в версии `rewrite` не надо писать в дужках `command()` pass_context

И зачем вам еще одна такая строка?

```
client = commands.Bot
```